# How to get value from HTML form in Azure function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-functions

I have Azure blob storage, a .NET Core MVC application with a simple form, which contains an input type file, and a text field for user email. On form submission, the file sends to Blob storage, and my blob trigger function fires. The trigger sends a message to the user's email.

But how can I access this email in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Azure Function App is on .NET or C#, I recommend creating a custom class as parameter on submit. This custom class can have the properties of the data you need to pass to your next function.

Depending on the use case you have, you can also use the Function Chaining Pattern using Azure Durable Functions

The following documentation might be helpful:

- [Azure Functions Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference?tabs=blob)
- [Azure Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp-inproc?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004251)